# How to add tooltip to telerik treeview

Tags: telerik, treeview, asp.net-mvc-5, tooltip

I am using a Telerik Treeview control and I've been asked to add tooltips to one level of the branches, each branch would have a different tooltip.  First is there any easy way to add a tooltip to a node in the Treeview control and second could I be able to attach different tool tips to each node?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://www.telerik.com/forums/show-tooltip-for-each-treeview-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a very easy thing, so easy in fact I missed it for way to long.

A TreeeViewItemModel has an HtmlAttributes property , by adding a 'title' attribute with the tooltip you want, it works automagicially.  Very simple to pick and choose which nodes have tooltips and what they are, if you know that 'title' is really the 'tooltip'.

```
 foreach (item in r.ListOfItems)
 {
      TreeViewItemModel tvim = new TreeViewItemModel();
      tvim .Id = item.ID.ToString();
      tvim .Text = item.Value.ToString();
      tvim.HtmlAttributes.Add("title", item.SomeField);
      tvim .Add(tvimzip);
 }
```